# Regular expression for a root and a few variations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like to match the strings '364.1', '364.10', '364.11', but nothing else. I know I can use

```
select '364.1' regexp '364\.1$|364\.1[01]'    ---> 1
```

But is there a more elegant way, my ideal would be something like this where I fill in the underscore with the elusive piece that indicates matching the end of the string, 0, or 1 in that position:

```
select '364.1' regexp '364\.1[_01]'   ---> 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `in ( '364.1', '364.10', '364.11')`?

Comment: I'll be applying to larger sets, so something generalizable where I don't have to type everything would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like `'^364\.1[01]?$'` ?

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for